# How to test express app headless with Mocha and Zombie.js

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, zombie.js

I am trying to run some Mocha/Zombie.js tests on my new node.js (express) app.

Now I want to do it without having to restart the node app.

Now, I have a working test, something like this:

```
var assert=require('assert')
    , Browser = require("zombie")
    ;

var browser = new Browser();
browser.site = "http://domain.com";
browser.silent = false;

describe('Home page', function(){
    describe ('Page title', function(){
        it('should open a home page', function(done){
            browser.visit('/').
            then(function(done){
                assert.equal(browser.text("title"), "My page title");
                done();
            }).fail(function(err){
                done(err);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

So, when the test fails, I change the page title, *reload the app* and then re-run the test so it passes.

I know I can do something like:

```
var server = require('../server');
var browser = new Browser();
```

I just don't know how, and I can't see from Mocha and Zombie example pages.

How do I tell the browser.visit to visit the *server* and not the real deployed web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was suggested on chat here, I am using [Node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor) - a supervisor for node apps, to which I say what to watch and restart the app automatically when it changes.